# Using name attribute for Propel joins

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreign-keys, propel

I lately started to use Propel (PHP ORM) and I love it but I have one quite annoying issue I can't resolve even with a lot of trying. I use reverse engineering to create my schema.xml, which works great until it comes to joins. Sadly for all my foreign keys the reverse engineering only adds the `name` and not the `phpName` attribute. Whatever I try to use this `name` attribute for a join I fail. After I added the `phpName` attribute manually (and then rebuilding the models of course) the join works fine as it should.

Here is the snippet of the foreign key in the schema.xml (without the phpName attribute obviously):

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="users" name="messages_ibfk_1">
  <reference local="creating_user_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
```

And here is the code for my join (which doesn't work):

```
$messages = MessagesQuery::create()->joinWith('messages_ibfk_1')->findByRecipientId($id);
```

I tried all kinds of variations for the `joinWith` value but none worked. On top of the schema this setting is active: `defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore"`

The error propel pulls out is: `Unknown relation messages_ibfk_1 on the Messages table.`

If I add the `phpName` attribut with the value `Author` the join works fine like that:

```
$messages = MessagesQuery::create()->joinWith('Author')->findByRecipientId($id);
```

As I have a lot of foreign keys and I want minimum/none manual work the question is: How do I resolve this without adding all the `phpName` attributes manually. Either I find a way to access the foreign keys with their regular name attribute or there is a way to tell propel to set up the `phpName` attribute while building the models?

I hope someone has an idea, would be a great help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreign-key`s `name` attribute is only being used for schema migration, not for the usage in your actual PHP code. So either you define everywhere a useful `phpName` or you extend `MysqlSchemaParser` for example and add there something like:

```
$fk->setPhpName($name);
```

https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/master/src/Propel/Generator/Reverse/MysqlSchemaParser.php#L349

You can then use this new reverse class by using the `migration.parserClass` configuration property.
More information here http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#reverse-engeneering. Keep in mind: If you change this property, you aren't able to pass a DSN for the `database:reverse` command anymore. You need to pass a connection name to it, defined in your propel configuration under `propel.database.connections`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer, especially all the details. I might try your solution in the future. As I didn't get an answer for a few days I helped myself by writing a tiny command line tool that adds the phpName attribute for every foreign key in the schema. It's a bit sad that this can't be activated by a simple parameter though I think but that's, of course, not your fault. Your help is highly appreciated, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The name `messages_ibfk_1` refers to the name of the index in your physical table, and not a relation/table.  joinWith() requires the table name, in this case it should be `joinWith('users')`, which, according to your schema definition is the foreign table.

So the correct synax should be:

`$messages = MessagesQuery::create()->joinWith('users')->findByRecipientId($id);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly this doesn't work though. I don't know if it doesn't work in general or just because I have multiple foreign keys pointing to the same table.